# Boost DYN_LNK vs. USE_DLL vs. USE_LIB

Tags: boost, boost-thread, bjam, boost-regex, boost-build

What is the difference between the following defines:

```
#define BOOST_REGEX_DYN_LNK
#define BOOST_REGEX_USE_DLL
#define BOOST_REGEX_USE_LIB
```

(regex was chosen arbitrarily)?

Which of them auto-link the project with `libboost*.lib`, `boost*.lib`, `boost*.dll` files? what are the differences between the mentioned files.